# Экспорт xlsx файла из php

Tags: php, excel, export, xlsx

Пытаюсь сделать экспорт данных в xlsx файл. Сначала сделал экспорт в xls таким образом:

1) Вывожу нужные данные на страницу с помощью `echo`

2) Выполняю код:

```
$xls_data = ob_get_clean();

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");

echo $xls_data;
exit();
```

3)  Получаю файл export.xls - то есть всё работает.

Проблема возникла с xlsx. Поискал на разных источниках какие нужно писать заголовки для экспорта xlsx, но всевозможные варианты не работают. Файл скачивается, но открыть его не удаётся (ошибка "Файл повреждён или имеет неверное расширение").

Пробую экспортировать xlsx так:

```
$xls_data = ob_get_clean();

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xlsx");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

echo $xls_data;
exit();
```

Подскажите в чём моя ошибка?

P.S. Различные библиотеки для формирования xlsx прошу не предлагать.

Пример моего файла xlsx, открытого в блокноте:

```
<table border=1 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">№</td>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">Заголовок материала</td>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">Эксклюзив</td>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">Ссылка на материал на сайте</td>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">Дата публикации</td>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">Время публикации</td>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">Создатель материала</td>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">Автор материала</td>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">Категории</td>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">Просмотры</td>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">Просмотры 24</td>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">Теги</td>
<td style="padding:2px 5px; mso-number-format:\@;">Символы</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

Comment: Пользуйтесь встроенным классом  `$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38741010/save-a-xlsx-file-with-phpexcel

Comment: Кажется это ниразу не встроенный класс. На всех источниках его предлагают скачать и пользоваться. Мне нужно решить без использования дополнительных библиотек.

Comment: @AlMr если вы не пользуетесь дополнительными библиотеками, то как вы создали `xls` файл? Это должен быть бинарный файл, [OLE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding) и всё такое! Неужели cодержмое тоже самое и вы просто пытаетесь заголовки поменять? =)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующий пример:

```
$file = "myfile.xlsx" ;
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file );
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
readfile('myfile.xlsx');
```

> Если этот подход не решит вашу проблему то делаем -

**Вывод :**

Вы не сможете просто создать один без библиотеки. Прочитайте этот [**PHPExcel**](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) Github, который должен указать вам правильноe направлениe.

Существует много разных форматов файлов электронных таблиц, каждый из которых имеет свои собств> **BIFF Format**
>

> - Used by Microsoft Excel between versions 95 and 2003 File
> - **extension:** xls
> - **PHPEXcel Writer:** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5
> - **Mime Type:** application/vnd.ms-excel
>
> **OfficeOpenXML Format**
>
> - Used by Microsoft Excel since version 2007
> - **File extension:** xlsx
> - **PHPEXcel Writer:** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007
> - **Mime Type:** application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Попробуйте так

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=test.xlsx");
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=test.xls");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
$objWriter->setOffice2003Compatibility(true);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Не находит PHPExcel класс. Нужно решить без подключения доп. библиотек

Comment: @AlMr А пробовал твой вариант с моими заголовками ?

Comment: да. результат тот же

Comment: @AlMr Вы не сможете просто создать один без библиотеки. Прочитайте этот PHPExcel Github, который должен указать вам правильноe направлениe. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: @AlMr Почему не хочете пользоваться им.Этоже так просто.Скачали нужный пакет и всю жизнь пользуйтесь правильными решениями

Comment: На самом деле я не против пользоваться этой библиотекой. Просто правила устанавливаю не я.

Comment: @AlMr Так объясните ему чтоб устанавливал правильные правила .Если не поймет отправь ему эту ссылочку пусть читает.До этого я еще поищу решения

Comment: @AlMr Обновил ответ, пробуйте :)

Answer (score 1):

У вас `filename` в `Content-Disposition` не с тем расширением. Измените на `xslx`

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xlsx");
```

Ещё можно попробовать заменить `Content-Type` на `application/octet-stream`

**UPD 1**

В моём последнем проекте при экспорте `xslx` файла высылаются такие заголовки (из полного списка оставил только значимые):

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 6743
Cache-Control: public
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="users.xlsx"
```

**UPD 2**

Всё, что было написано выше касалось настоящих `xslx` файлов (т.е. тех, которые запакованы в zip)

Есть ещё один способ передавать данные в Excel - через HTML-таблицы. Создайте пустой файл `test.xls` со следующим содержимым:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл откроется в Excel. Здесь важно расширение файла `xls` и `<meta />` внутри html с `Content-Type`.

Чтобы передать такой файл с сервера я передавал такие заголовки:

```
Pragma: Public
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

Comment: Там в действительности `.xlsx` просто при составлении вопроса скопипастил) `application/octet-stream` не помогло

Comment: @AlMr обновил ответ. А быть может ваш файл действительно испорченный? `xslx` файлы на самом деле - это `zip` архивы. Попробуйте открыть его в каком-нибудь WinRAR. Если не откроет, то проблема не в заголовках

Comment: Действительно, 7ZIP-ом файл не открывается. Зато блокнотом - отлично открывается

Comment: @AlMr а там в файле HTML-код с таблицей? Если да, приложите к вопросу "урезанную версию" этого файла, пожалуйста

Comment: Там обычный `<table>` с `<tr>` и `<td>` внутри. И больше ничего

Comment: @AlMr это самое важное =) я обновил ответ. дополните и вопрос тоже вашим файлом с таблицей

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleXLSXGen](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsxgen)

```
$books = [
    ['ISBN', 'title', 'author', 'publisher', 'ctry' ],
    [618260307, 'The Hobbit', 'J. R. R. Tolkien', 'Houghton Mifflin', 'USA'],
    [908606664, 'Slinky Malinki', 'Lynley Dodd', 'Mallinson Rendel', 'NZ']
];
$xlsx = SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray( $books );
$xlsx->saveAs('books.xlsx');
//  $xlsx->downloadAs('books.xlsx');
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Report</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin', 'sfgcjm') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
$setSql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
    if (!$query = mysqli_query($conn, $setSql) ) {
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
        die();
    }
    $columnHeader = '';
    $columnHeader = "Name1" . "\t" . "Name2" . "\t" . "Name3" . "\n";

    $setData = '';

    while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) {
        $rowData = '';
        foreach ($rec as $value) {
            $value = $value . "\t";
            $rowData .= $value;
        }
        $setData .= trim($rowData) . "\n";
    }
    $result = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $result );


    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Mailing_list_Report.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    echo ucwords($columnHeader) . "\n" . $setData . "\n";

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
</body>

</html>

Либо так:


<?php

function cleanData(&$str)
{
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}
// Имя загружаемого файла файла.
$filename = "otchet_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".xls";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

// Подключение к бд
mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","admin");// Хост юзер и пароль
mysqli_select_db("mailing_list") or die (mysqli_error());// Имя базы данных

//Указать кодировку выводимых данных
mysqli_query('SET character_set_database = cp1251_general_ci');
mysqli_query ("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");

//запрос и вывод данных
$flag = false;
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM mailing_list ORDER BY Data DESC")
or die('Запрос не выполнен!');
while(false !== ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    if(!$flag) {
        // Вывод заголовков
        echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
        $flag = true;
    }
    //Вывод данных столбцов
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
}
exit;
```

Comment: Мне нужно экспортировать в xlsx а не xls как у Вас. Для чего мне ваш код в этой ситуации?

Comment: @AlMr так поменяйте розшерение и измените header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

Comment: я как раз так и делаю. в вопросе же указано